# OnClick() Handler for D3 using a Websocket

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, websocket

I am trying to create a Websocket in JS that passes a variable that is given to me when I click on a node in a D3. I have created most of the code to use static data so far but I cannot figure out a way to kick off the code when I click on the node to get the "user information" I am excluding the actually wsUri all I am looking for is how to get the variable back from OnClick on the D3 node which then will pass that "username" as a variable and bring the data back down the Websocket to display.

**Websocket:**

```
var jsonObject = "";
var username = "test_123";

function init() {
  testWebSocket();
}

function testWebSocket() {
  websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
  websocket.onopen = function(evt) {
    onOpen(evt)
  };
  websocket.onclose = function(evt) {
    onClose(evt)
  };
  websocket.onmessage = function(evt) {
    onMessage(evt)
    testObject();
  };
  websocket.onerror = function(evt) {
    onError(evt)
  };
}

function onOpen(evt) {
  console.log("CONNECTED");
  doSend('{"request":"getTweetRelationshipGraphForUser", "screen_name" : }');
}

function onClose(evt) {
  console.log("DISCONNECTED");
}

function onMessage(evt) {
  console.log("Message: " + evt.data);
  jsonObject = evt.data;
  console.log("json object: "+jsonObject);
  return jsonObject;
  //  websocket.close();
}

function onError(evt) {
  console.log("Error:" + evt.data);
}

function doSend(message) {
  console.log("SENT: " + message);
  websocket.send(message);
}

function testObject(){
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = jsonObject;
  console.log(jsonObject);
}

window.addEventListener("load", init, false);
```

**D3 Javascript**

```
function start() {
  var w = 1200,
    h = 600,
    radius = 10,
    node,
    link,
    root;

  var count = 0;

  var force = d3.layout.force()
    .on("tick", tick)
    .charge(function (d) {
      return -500;
    })
    .linkDistance(function (d) {
      return d.target._children ? 100 : 50;
    })
    .size([w, h - 160]);

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

  svg.append("rect")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", "100%")
    .attr("fill", "#000");

  root = JSON.parse(jsonObject);
  console.log("root" + root);
  root.fixed = true;
  root.x = w / 2;
  root.y = h / 2 - 80;
  update();

  function update() {
    var nodes = root.nodes,
      links = root.links;

    // Restart the force layout.
    force
      .nodes(nodes)
      .links(links)
      .start();

    // Update the links…
    link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(links);

    // Enter any new links.
    link.enter().insert("svg:line", ".node")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("x1", function (d) {
        return d.source.x;
      })
      .attr("y1", function (d) {
        return d.source.y;
      })
      .attr("x2", function (d) {
        return d.target.x;
      })
      .attr("y2", function (d) {
        return d.target.y;
      });

    // Exit any old links.
    link.exit().remove();

    // Update the nodes…
    node = svg.selectAll("circle.node")
      .data(nodes, function (d) {
        return d.name;
      })
      .style("fill", color);

    node.transition()
      .attr("r", radius);

    // Enter any new nodes.
    node.enter().append("svg:circle")
      .attr("xlink:href", function (d) {
        return d.image;
      })
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("cx", function (d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr("cy", function (d) {
        return d.y;
      })
      .attr("r", radius)
      .attr("r", function (d) {
        return d.size * 2;
      })
      .style("fill", color)
      .on("click", click)
      .call(force.drag);
    node.append("title")
      .text(function (d) {
        return d.name;
      });

    // Exit any old nodes.
    node.exit().remove();

    title = svg.selectAll("text.title")
      .data(nodes);

    // Enter any new titles.
    title.enter()
      .append("text")
      .attr("class", "title");
    //.text(function(d) { return d.name; });

    // Exit any old titles.
    title.exit().remove();
  }

  function tick() {
    link.attr("x1", function (d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
      .attr("y1", function (d) {
        return d.source.y;
      })
      .attr("x2", function (d) {
        return d.target.x;
      })
      .attr("y2", function (d) {
        return d.target.y;
      });

    node.attr("cx", function (d) {
      return d.x;
    })
      .attr("cy", function (d) {
        return d.y;
      });

    title.attr("transform", function (d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });
  }

  // Color leaf nodes orange, and packages white or blue.
  function color(d) {
    if (d._children) {
      return "#95a5a6";
    } else {
      switch (d.group) {
        case 'r': //adverb
          return "#e74c3c";
          break;
        case 'n': //noun
          return "#3498db";
          break;
        case 'v': //verb
          return "#2ecc71";
          break;
        case 's': //adjective
          return "#e78229";
          break;
        default:
          return "rgb(0, 238, 238)";
      }
    }
  }

  // Toggle children on click.
  function click(d) {
    document.getElementById("image").src = d.image;
    document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = "Username:" + d.name;
    document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = "ID:" + d.id;
    document.getElementById("friends").innerHTML = d.friend;
    document.getElementById("nodeTitle").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("size").innerHTML = d.size;
    //document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = "Friend Count:" + d.name;
    //if (d._children)
    //grabImage();
    //document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = (d.image);

    /*if (d.children) { 
     d._children = d.children;
     d.children = null;
     } else {
     d.children = d._children;
     d._children = null;
     }
     update();*/
  }

  function mouseover() {
    d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr("r", 16);
  }


  function mouseout() {
    d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr("r", 8);
  }

  // Returns a list of all nodes under the root.
  function flatten(root) {
    var nodes = [], i = 0;

    function recurse(node) {
      if (node.children) node.size = node.children.reduce(function (p, v) {
        return p + recurse(v);
      }, 0);
      if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
      nodes.push(node);
      return node.size;
    }

    root.size = recurse(root);
    return nodes;
  }
}

do {
  var intervalID = window.setTimeout(start, 1000)
} while (jsonObject != "") {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per understanding of your requirements I am making slight modification to your code. Currently I am also working websockets to fetch financial data and d3.js to visualize it. All you need to set an initiation point to websocket and a rendering initiation point for d3 code and it should be in closed loop as when user clicks on the node information will be send to websocket and after getting data from web socket chart will be refreshed.

```
`    var jsonObject = "";
        var username = "test_123";

        function init() {
          testWebSocket();
        }

        function testWebSocket() {
          websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
          websocket.onopen = function(evt) {
            onOpen(evt)
          };
          websocket.onclose = function(evt) {
            onClose(evt)
          };
          websocket.onmessage = function(evt) {
            onMessage(evt)
            testObject();
          };
          websocket.onerror = function(evt) {
            onError(evt)
          };
        }

        function onOpen(evt) {
          console.log("CONNECTED");
          doSend('{"request":"getTweetRelationshipGraphForUser", "screen_name" : }');
        }

        function onClose(evt) {
          console.log("DISCONNECTED");
        }

        function onMessage(evt) {
          console.log("Message: " + evt.data);
          jsonObject = evt.data;

    //initiate the d3 rendering with new JSON
    start(jsonObject);


          console.log("json object: "+jsonObject);
          return jsonObject;
           }

        function onError(evt) {
          console.log("Error:" + evt.data);
        }

        function doSend(message) {

          websocket.send(message);
        }

      function initiateForInput(userName){
       //updating userinfo to JSON and send the wrapper to doSend
      var userInfoJson='{"request":"getTweetRelationshipGraphForUser", "screen_name" :'+userName+' }';
       doSend(userInfoJson);
    }


        function testObject(){
          document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = jsonObject;
          console.log(jsonObject);
        }

        window.addEventListener("load", init, false);
```

d3 file:-

```
    function start(newJsonObject) {
  var w = 1200,
    h = 600,
    radius = 10,
    node,
    link,
    root;

  var count = 0;

  var force = d3.layout.force()
    .on("tick", tick)
    .charge(function (d) {
      return -500;
    })
    .linkDistance(function (d) {
      return d.target._children ? 100 : 50;
    })
    .size([w, h - 160]);

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

  svg.append("rect")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", "100%")
    .attr("fill", "#000");

  root = JSON.parse(newJsonObject);
  console.log("root" + root);
  root.fixed = true;
  root.x = w / 2;
  root.y = h / 2 - 80;
  update();

  function update() {
    var nodes = root.nodes,
      links = root.links;

    // Restart the force layout.
    force
      .nodes(nodes)
      .links(links)
      .start();

    // Update the links…
    link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(links);

    // Enter any new links.
    link.enter().insert("svg:line", ".node")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("x1", function (d) {
        return d.source.x;
      })
      .attr("y1", function (d) {
        return d.source.y;
      })
      .attr("x2", function (d) {
        return d.target.x;
      })
      .attr("y2", function (d) {
        return d.target.y;
      });

    // Exit any old links.
    link.exit().remove();

    // Update the nodes…
    node = svg.selectAll("circle.node")
      .data(nodes, function (d) {
        return d.name;
      })
      .style("fill", color);

    node.transition()
      .attr("r", radius);

    // Enter any new nodes.
    node.enter().append("svg:circle")
      .attr("xlink:href", function (d) {
        return d.image;
      })
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("cx", function (d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr("cy", function (d) {
        return d.y;
      })
      .attr("r", radius)
      .attr("r", function (d) {
        return d.size * 2;
      })
      .style("fill", color)
      .on("click", click)
      .call(force.drag);
    node.append("title")
      .text(function (d) {
        return d.name;
      });

    // Exit any old nodes.
    node.exit().remove();

    title = svg.selectAll("text.title")
      .data(nodes);

    // Enter any new titles.
    title.enter()
      .append("text")
      .attr("class", "title");
    //.text(function(d) { return d.name; });

    // Exit any old titles.
    title.exit().remove();
  }

  function tick() {
    link.attr("x1", function (d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
      .attr("y1", function (d) {
        return d.source.y;
      })
      .attr("x2", function (d) {
        return d.target.x;
      })
      .attr("y2", function (d) {
        return d.target.y;
      });

    node.attr("cx", function (d) {
      return d.x;
    })
      .attr("cy", function (d) {
        return d.y;
      });

    title.attr("transform", function (d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });
  }

  // Color leaf nodes orange, and packages white or blue.
  function color(d) {
    if (d._children) {
      return "#95a5a6";
    } else {
      switch (d.group) {
        case 'r': //adverb
          return "#e74c3c";
          break;
        case 'n': //noun
          return "#3498db";
          break;
        case 'v': //verb
          return "#2ecc71";
          break;
        case 's': //adjective
          return "#e78229";
          break;
        default:
          return "rgb(0, 238, 238)";
      }
    }
  }

  // Toggle children on click.
  function click(d) {
    document.getElementById("image").src = d.image;
    document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = "Username:" + d.name;
    document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = "ID:" + d.id;
    document.getElementById("friends").innerHTML = d.friend;
    document.getElementById("nodeTitle").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("size").innerHTML = d.size;



    //command to websockets

    initiateForInput(d.name);






    //document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = "Friend Count:" + d.name;
    //if (d._children)
    //grabImage();
    //document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = (d.image);

    /*if (d.children) { 
     d._children = d.children;
     d.children = null;
     } else {
     d.children = d._children;
     d._children = null;
     }
     update();*/
  }

  function mouseover() {
    d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr("r", 16);
  }


  function mouseout() {
    d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr("r", 8);
  }

  // Returns a list of all nodes under the root.
  function flatten(root) {
    var nodes = [], i = 0;

    function recurse(node) {
      if (node.children) node.size = node.children.reduce(function (p, v) {
        return p + recurse(v);
      }, 0);
      if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
      nodes.push(node);
      return node.size;
    }

    root.size = recurse(root);
    return nodes;
  }
}

do {
  var intervalID = window.setTimeout(start, 1000)
} while (jsonObject != "") {

}
```

Comment: In case of any ambiguity just let me know.

Comment: You are being pretty ambiguous. I am trying to have the user click a node it runs the websocket to pull data each time for every unique node clicked and it is passing the "screename" as a variable on the request to return information about them.

Comment: a screenname will be associated with each node?

Comment: I am passing "username" from click method and invoking the doSend via
initiateForInput(d.name). Using this you can form your required input and send it via websocket. Again when when you receive the JSON, you can pass it start(newjson) method.  Where is the glitch?

Comment: Yes one more thing you should do is clear the placeholder which is body in your case before reploting the chart.

Comment: Every single node will be a different user and on each ONClick() I want to fetch data via a websocket and receive the data on a user. So passing the username ONClick() down to a websocket and it returns my data.

Comment: So what I have suggested is doing that only!

Comment: I am confused cause in the  doSend('{"request":"getTweetRelationshipGraphForUser", "screen_name" : }');
        }   you failed to pass the username as a parameter in fact this fails

Comment: k...got your problem..I will change the response and pass dynamically username instead of screenname.

Comment: changed the response...   function initiateForInput(userName){
       //updating userinfo to JSON and send the wrapper to doSend
      var userInfoJson='{"request":"getTweetRelationshipGraphForUser", "screen_name" :'+userName+' }';
       doSend(userInfoJson);
    }....                 kindly check the answer

Comment: I am referring to onOpen() not  function initiateForInput(userName)

Comment: bro ultimately you have to call send after socket is opened. You can create an instance for socket and after onOpen you can give control to user to click on node....On other hand you can keep all the logic related to websocket into a function and then call it from node click. But in this case you have to kill last instance every time